# Side on mouse that has backward and forward,I would like to disable the backward button as I am left handed and keep hitting the button

Tags: mouse

I have a mouse with side buttons and I keep hitting the backward button with my fingers because I am left handed. I keep having to start over and over again, how can I disable the backward button on the side?

Answer (score 0):

YMMV depending on the exact make and model of your mouse and what platform you are interfacing, but here are some generalized methods that come to mind:

- Your mouse's OEM software (if applicable) should have further configurations, and in many cases you can control key bindings and macros; you should have the option to disable or rebind the key in question.
- In some cases, you can use 3rd party utilities or software if the mouse has that interoperability.  Some are proprietary and not compatible out-of-box, research your exact make and model to find out.
- Your OS userspace hardware settings may or may not include the capability to do so.
- For Windows OS you can utilize something such as AHK to achieve the desired results (mostly, with some exceptions based on aforementioned limitations).  The script can be compiled into a portable `.exe` — which I would suggest you attach to your mouse via USB storage or some other means — so you don't have to worry about compatibility as long as the workstation is running Windows.
- If all else fails, open the mouse up and disconnect the switch for that button!

Comment: thank you so much